# Is the deceleration a result of friction, a constant value?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, friction

Frictional Force = km, therefore k = a

Would this mean that no matter the mass of an object (if they are the same material)

They will decelerate at the same speed with friction, therefore if u is the same then would s also be equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frictional force=$k$*weight=$k*m*g$ (you need gravity in there to convert mass to weight)

So yes, frictional force is proportional to weight which is proportional to mass so deceleration rate is constant, IF there aren't any other forces.

Take cars as an example: the range of stopping distances for cars is quite small, because every modern car has tires with a similar coefficient of friction, and good enough brakes/ABS to keep the wheels on or near the limit of skidding.

https://www.consumerreports.org/car-safety/best-and-worst-braking-distances-a2960086475/ shows there's only about a 10% difference between small cars and big trucks in stopping distance, despite the mass/weight differing by a factor of 4 between small hatchbacks and large trucks/SUVs. (The small difference is from a mixture of slightly different coefficients of friction from tire sizes/pressures/materials/tread patters, plus aerodynamic effects)

The one exception is when there's aerodynamic downforce, which makes the force on the wheels higher than the weight of the car, so sporty cars stop noticeably shorter (10% shorter than small cars according to the article).

Answer (score 0):

It is generally assumed that sliding kinetic friction, $μ_k$N, is independent of speed. On the other hand, fluid friction (with the air or a liquid) does increase with an increase in speed.

Comment: I think the question was rather if two identical objects, except one more massive than the other, were to slide on the same surface, would the deceleration due to friction be the same. Analogous to objects in a vacuum having the same acceleration due to gravity.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible friction forces that can cause deceleration: Static friction and kinetic friction. Take the case of deceleration of a car.

When you apply the brakes, the torque applied to the wheel results is the wheel applying a force on the road acting in the direction of the motion of the car. Per Newton's third law the road applies an equal and opposite friction force in the direction opposite the motion of the vehicle, causing it to decelerate.

If the wheel does not skid on the road, the force that causes deceleration is static friction which prevents relative motion between the wheel and the road. See FIG 1 below. The static friction force applied by the road to the wheel is equal and opposite to the force the wheel exerts on the road up until the maximum static friction force $f_{s}(max)$ is reached, which is give by

$$f_{s}(max)=\mu_{s}N$$

Where  $\mu_s$ is the coefficient of static friction and $N$ normal force, or the fraction of the weight of the car supported by the wheel. If the braking force exceeds this value, the wheel will "lock. up" causing the car to skid as the friction force now becomes kinetic (sliding) friction force $f_k$. See FIG 2 below. Where $f_k$ is given by

$$f_{k}=\mu_{k}N$$

where $\mu_k$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction, which is generally less than the coefficient of static friction.  For a limited range of speeds the kinetic friction force is generally considered constant (independent of speed).

Since the coefficient of kinetic friction is less than static friction, the deceleration during skidding would be less and stopping distance longer. Thus the benefit of an anti-lock braking system (ABS).

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]